# python regular expression doesn't work

Tags: python, regex

I have this android logcat's log:

"Could not find class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder, referenced from method b.a"

and I'm trying to apply a regular expression, in python, to extract android.app.Notification$Action$Builder and b.a.

I use this code:

```
regexp = '\'([\w\d\.\$\:\-\[\]\<\>]+).*\s([\w\d\.\$\:\-\[\]\<\>]+)'
match = re.match(r'%s' % regexp, msg, re.M | re.I)
```

I tested the regular expression online and it works as expected, but it never matches in python. Someone can give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `r'%s' % regexp` doesn't make the regular expression a raw string literal. Put the `r` on the `regex = r'...'` string instead.

Comment: Not that it matters here. [You should be using `re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#match-versus-search).

Comment: Aside, `'%s' % some_string` is a non-sensical complexity. Prefer using `some_string` directly. In your case, prefer `re.match(regexp, msg, re.M | re.I)`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you claim it works in an online regular expression tester. [It doesn't for me](https://regex101.com/r/nV5sU9/1).

Answer (score 1):

.`re.match()` matches *only at the start* of a string. Use `re.search()` instead, see [*`match()` vs. `search()`*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#match-versus-search).

Note that you appear to misunderstand what a raw string literal is; `r'%s' % string` does not produce a special, different object. `r'..'` is just *notation*, it still produces a regular string object. Put the `r` on the original string literal instead (but if you use double quotes you do not need to quote the single quote contained):

```
regexp = r"'([\w\d\.\$\:\-\[\]\<\>]+).*\s([\w\d\.\$\:\-\[\]\<\>]+)"
```

For *this specific regex* it doesn't otherwise matter to the pattern produced.

Note that the pattern doesn't actually capture what you want to capture. Apart from the escaped `'` at the start (which doesn't appear in your text *at all*, it won't work as it doesn't *require* dots and dollars to be part of the name. As such, you capture `Could` and `b.a` instead, the first and last words in the regular expression.

I'd anchor on the words `class` and `method` instead, and perhaps require there to be dots in the class name:

```
regexp = r'class\s+((?:[\w\d\$\:\-\[\]\<\>]+\.)+[\w\d\$\:\-\[\]\<\>]+).*method ([\w\d.\$\:\-\[\]\<\>]+)'
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> regexp = r'class\s+((?:[\w\d\$\:\-\[\]\<\>]+\.)+[\w\d\$\:\-\[\]\<\>]+).*method ([\w\d.\$\:\-\[\]\<\>]+)'
>>> msg = "Could not find class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder, referenced from method b.a"
>>> re.search(regexp, msg, re.M | re.I)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1023072d8>
>>> re.search(regexp, msg, re.M | re.I).groups()
('android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', 'b.a')
```